# warnings in playing with bits

Tags: c++

```
 BYTE original = 0xF0F0;
     BYTE bMask = 0x0000;
BYTE wMask = 0xFFFF;
BYTE  newBits = 0xAAAA;

/*& operation with "0bit set 0" & "1bit give no change to original byte" */
cout<<"Original o: "<<bits(original)<<endl;
cout<<"NewBits: "<<bits(newBits)<<endl;
cout<<"BMask m: "<<bits(bMask)<<endl;
cout<<"WMask m: "<<bits(wMask)<<endl;
cout<<"o & m with BMask: "<<bits(original & bMask)<<endl;/*0 set original bit as 0 */
cout<<"o & m with WMak: "<<bits(original & wMask)<<endl;/*1 bit put no effect on image*/
cout<<"Result"<<bits(original & wMask | newBits)<<endl;
```

My OutPut is right but i am getting warnings...

first i did declaration with char type because char take 1Byte in memory.. but still that give me warning,...

Then i apply BYTE byte instead of char...because BYTE also take 1Byte in memory..

Warnings:
warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value

this warning is on all declaration lines.. 
If char and Byte take 1Byte in memory then why i am getting warning..
what am i missing here? Can any one help me..
Expecting a good response 
Thanks

Comment: Please do't close the question... you can say me directly that question is not clear.. but please do't close it...

Comment: All your initializer constants are *2 bytes*. Why are you expecting them to fit into 1 byte???

Comment: Hexadecimal numbers are 4 bits and the value you are trying to store is 16 bits. You need two bytes to store those constants so try `unsigned short` instead of `BYTE` which is just 1 byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g. `0xF0F0` requires 16 bits - 2 bytes. Try with an `unsigned short` instead of `BYTE`

Comment: @Erik: why unsigned short.. ?

Comment: @Miss: Because I'm guessing it's 16 bits wide on your platform. If you happen to be on a platform where it's smaller, use an unsigned int or long.

Comment: @Miss: Your constants are 16 bits wide. If you do not get a warning when assigning to an unsigned short, then your unsigned short is at least 16 bits wide.

Comment: @Miss: You're declaring a BYTE which is 1 byte in size. You're trying to store 0xF0F0 in that byte, even though 0xF0F0 needs two bytes of storage. It's too big to fit in the box! An unsigned short, however, is typically two bytes in size - a box big enough for 0xF0F0.

Answer (score 0):

1 Byte = 8 Bits. 0xf0f0 is 16 Bits.

Comment: i do't know which data type i should use and why?

Comment: You can check which type to use (if you don't know it about your platform) with `sizeof(datatype)`. Use it `cout << sizeof(byte) << " " << sizeof(unsigned int << (and so on)` until you find which one is 2 bytes long.

Comment: well unsigned int & unsigned long takes 4 bytes on my machine

Answer (score 0):

`0xf0f0`, `0xffff` and `0xaaaa` are two bytes constant, a `short int` in other words.

The compiler is just warning you that it is throwing away the most significant bytes of the two you are assigning:

`0xf0f0` => compiler assigns `0xf0`;
`0xffff` => compiler assigns `0xff`;
`0xaaaa` => compiler assigns `0xaa`;

The question is: why do you want to assign a 2-byte constant to something you expect to be 1-byte sized?

Comment: @simone: well i assign 2-byte but i get 1 byte result...i just want to see the result that what happen when i assign 2 byte...

Comment: The constants are actually ints - but they convert without loss to unsigned short so there's no need for a compiler warning

Comment: @Erik: thanks can you please see this question also :http://stackoverflow.com/q/5650408/705418

Comment: @Miss: That question is closed - can't be answered. It was likely closed because you say "i am not getting right output" without explaining what "right output" is - noone are able to guess what you *want* to do unless you explain it.

Comment: @Erik: oo i mean i am getting original image as a result.. that is not right output....

Comment: @Miss: I'd suggest you sit down and take the time to write that question again - explaining exactly what you try to do, what you expected your code to do, what actually happens - and then post a new question.

Comment: @Erik:well i hope  it will again close because of reputation.